# How to get row count as column

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, count, distinct

So I have a query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT colB FROM tbl WHERE colA = "foo" LIMIT 0, 20
```

which gets me an array with max. 20 records where `colA` matches `"foo"`, but without duplicate records. Each array entry contains an associative array that contains the value of `colB`, like

```
0 => array(
       'colB' => 'some_value',
     ),
1 => array(
       'colB' => 'other_value',
     )
```

Can I also get the `COUNT()` for `colB` value? I mean this:

```
SELECT COUNT() as cbCount FROM tbl WHERE colA = "foo" AND colB = "some_value"
SELECT COUNT() as cbCount FROM tbl WHERE colA = "foo" AND colB = "other_value"
```

But included in the first query as another array field, like:

```
0 => array(
       'colB' => 'some_value',
       'cbCount' => 5,
     ),
1 => array(
       'colB' => 'other_value',
       'cbCount' => 2,
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Group By` with `Count` -

```
SELECT 
        colB, count(colB) as cbCount
FROM    
        tbl 
WHERE  
        colA = 'foo' 
GROUP BY 
        colB 
LIMIT 
        0, 20
```

This query will fetch the first 20 rows, group them according to the distinct values of `colB` and give their count.

Comment: so DISTINCT is not required?

Comment: @AnnaK.: Nope, not in this case. `Group By` will take care of it. Try executing it, you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is to use `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT  colB,
        COUNT(colB) AS cbCount
FROM    tableName
WHERE   colA = 'Foo'
GROUP   BY colB
```